# How to get unique occurrences from a file?

Tags: linux, perl, bash, sed, awk

I am having some problems trying to get unique occurrences of the `DeviceId` from a log file that has a similar format to the following:

```
log: {"deviceInfo":{"DeviceId":"123","device":"Android"}
log: {"deviceInfo":{"device":"Android","DeviceId":"123"}
log: {"deviceInfo":{"device":"Android","DeviceId":"234"}
log: {"deviceInfo":{"device":"iPhone","DeviceId":"323"}
log: {"deviceInfo":{"device":"iPhone","DeviceId":"323"}
```

What I am expecting is an output like this:

```
log: {"deviceInfo":{"DeviceId":"123","device":"Android"}
log: {"deviceInfo":{"device":"Android","DeviceId":"234"}
log: {"deviceInfo":{"device":"iPhone","DeviceId":"323"}
```

I tried using `awk` but I can seem to figure it out. Does anyone know how to do this?

I know there should be a way to just print the `DeviceId` using `awk` but I cant seem to figure it out.  Once I do get the `DeviceId` I can just pipe to `sort` and `uniq`.

Comment: This looks like [extended] JSON syntax, you might use a JSON parsing library

Comment: Does your input really have a missing closing curly bracket at the end of each line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Perl:

```
perl -lne 'if ( m{"DeviceId":" ([^"]+) "}xms ) { print if not $seen{$1}++; }' <log
```

Comment: Then try `cat log | perl ...`. Does that work? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk:

```
gawk 'match($0, /DeviceId":"([^"]+)/, a) && seen[a[1]]++ == 0' log
```

Given your input, this outputs

```
log: {"deviceInfo":{"DeviceId":"123","device":"Android"}
log: {"deviceInfo":{"device":"Android","DeviceId":"234"}
log: {"deviceInfo":{"device":"iPhone","DeviceId":"323"}
```

(*Note, this is essentially the gawk translation of [@Perleone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15073371/7552) although I did not notice at the time*)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @cnicutar's answer, use `sed`, `sort` and `cut`:

```
sed 's/.*\"DeviceId":"\([0-9]*\).*/\1\t\0/' <file> | sort -u -k 1,1 | cut -f 2
```

Output:

```
log: {"deviceInfo":{"DeviceId":"123","device":"Android"}
log: {"deviceInfo":{"device":"Android","DeviceId":"234"}
log: {"deviceInfo":{"device":"iPhone","DeviceId":"323"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unique device ID's using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/DeviceId/&&!a[$1]++&&gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"")' RS='[{,}]' file
123
234
323
```

The nice thing with `awk` is associative arrays, no need to pipe to `sort -u`.

Answer (score 1):

With any awk:

```
$ awk '{id=$0;gsub(/.*DeviceId":"|".*/,"",id)} !seen[id]++' file
log: {"deviceInfo":{"DeviceId":"123","device":"Android"}
log: {"deviceInfo":{"device":"Android","DeviceId":"234"}
log: {"deviceInfo":{"device":"iPhone","DeviceId":"323"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to parse JSON (but another quick awk):

```
awk -F'.*DeviceId":"|["}]' '!A[$2]++' file
```

---

Applying Ed Morton's suggestion for shaving off 3 more characters:

```
awk -F'.*DeviceId":"|"' '!A[$2]++' file
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution, wish I'd thought of it! You could shave a couple of characters by doing `|"` instead of `|["}]` if you like.

Comment: Thanks :) Good idea, indeed the 3 characters are unnecessary